# Cocoa Animation not triggering when called by button

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, animation

I'm developing an iOS app and i've been asked to add animations to make it more user friendly.
So i want to animate a badge on my button displaying quantity. When the quantity changes, my function valueForItemChanged is called, then i change the value in the bimButtonBadge label and i use a animation which makes its size bounce.
But I'm facing a problem: when i call .animateWithDuration() from an event triggered by a button, it doesn't work:

```
 @IBAction func valueForItemChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("value changed");
    self.bimButtonBadge.text = String(self.getTotalItemQuantity())
    self.bimButtonBadge.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
            initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
            animations: {
                self.bimButtonBadge.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }, completion: nil)
}
```

So i tried to make this animation in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), just to see. It worked.
I think viewDidLayoutSubview is called from the main thread so i tried this :

```
@IBAction func valueForItemChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("value changed");
    self.bimButtonBadge.text = String(self.getTotalItemQuantity())
    self.bimButtonBadge.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
            initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
            animations: {
                self.bimButtonBadge.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }, completion: nil)
    });
}
```

Aaaaaand, it worked, partially. Sometimes the label disappears. I searched on the web, but i couldn't find anything related to this. So i'm wondering where i'm wrong.

If anyone could answer me it would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your animation (both versions) sets the badge's transform to the identity transform, but you don't show any code that sets the transform to anything other than the identity transform. An animation animates a change in a property. If you don't actually change anything, it won't animate.

What are you trying to do? You say you're using a bounce animation, but what do you mean? Bouncing the size? The position?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i edited my question. I made a mistake, it's not that the animation does not triggers it's that the label disappears. I also added line where i first change it's size. But i really don't understand why i must call this function in the main thread.

Comment: ALL UI changes must be done on the main thread. No exceptions. If you are running this code from the background then that is a cause of your problems. "Results are undefined".

Comment: You can use `performSelectorOnMainThread` or `       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...` to invoke UI Changes on the main thread from code that runs on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I solved this by doing my first transformation in the main thread thanks to Duncan C.
My code is now :

```
@IBAction func valueForItemChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
print("value changed");
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.bimButtonBadge.text = String(self.getTotalItemQuantity())
    self.bimButtonBadge.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
        initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
        animations: {
            self.bimButtonBadge.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }, completion: nil)
});
```

}